# How to establish continues connection between server and android device whose ip addres keeps changing?

Tags: java, android, ip, ip-address

I want to my server to communicate to a android device whose `ip address` keep changing.How could server identify this android device.

Answer (score 0):

Just like a browser maintains a session variable for every request betweeen the user and the client, keep sending the session variable between the client and the server, so that we can have a nice conversation going on between them. If there is no session, then start a new session.

Make sure session is a long.

Thanks!